# CakePHP / MySQL - table relations

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp

I am playing around with CakePHP framework and its baking methods. So, firstly I've made a database and then I started baking - it turned out almost perfectly.

## Background

So, I have 3 tables: users, projects and project_helper. 
First two tables are standard ones i.e.:

**Users:**

- id
- login
- password
- email

**Users:**

- id
- title
- description

The thing is that one project can belong to many users, and each user can have many projects. To avoid making i.e. new column "projects" in user table and saving projects id in string (2,6,11,77) and exploding them into array later I decided to create another table with two primary keys (both columns).

**Project_helper:**

- user_id
- project_id

And it kind of worked, I can list all projects belonging to specified user etc.

However, as there is no real association between these tables I can't assign users to a project (unless I add them manually in db).

**Project_helper** table has references to users & projects, but neither users nor project has reference to project_helper or each other.

As I understand, I've made many-to-many relationship by creating project_helper table, and if I learned correctly from this tut:
http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/many-to-many-relationships/
I've done it right, rest of the work is managed by queries.

## Actual question

What I want to achive is that while creating new project it has to have atleast one user assigned (later on, when there will be a login system it will be the creator of project as its first member, but now it doesn't matter I guess).

There should be an dropdown input to select users and assign them to this project. 
There is no controller or view or whatever for third table (projects_helper). And I hope there is no need to make one.

Have I done something wrong with db and it is possible to generate (bake) it automatically?

## Same generated code:

```
// model/table/ProjectsTables

class ProjectsTable extends Table
{

/**
 * Initialize method
 *
 * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
 * @return void
 */
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('projects');
    $this->setDisplayField('title');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->hasMany('ProjectsGroup', [
        'foreignKey' => 'project_id'
    ]);
}

/**
 * Default validation rules.
 *
 * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
 * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
 */
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->integer('id')
        ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('title', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('title');

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('description', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('description');

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('logo', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('logo');

    return $validator;
}
```

model/table/UserTable

```
class UsersTable extends Table
{

/**
 * Initialize method
 *
 * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
 * @return void
 */
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('users');
    $this->setDisplayField('id');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->hasMany('ProjectsGroup', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
    ]);
}

/**
 * Default validation rules.
 *
 * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
 * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
 */
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->integer('id')
        ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('login', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('login');

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('password', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('password');

    $validator
        ->email('email')
        ->requirePresence('email', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('email');

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('avatar', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('avatar');

    $validator
        ->dateTime('lastvisited')
        ->requirePresence('lastvisited', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('lastvisited');

    $validator
        ->integer('lastip')
        ->requirePresence('lastip', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('lastip');

    return $validator;
}

/**
 * Returns a rules checker object that will be used for validating
 * application integrity.
 *
 * @param \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker $rules The rules object to be modified.
 * @return \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker
 */
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['login']));
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email']));

    return $rules;
}
```

Template/Projects/add.ctp

```
<?php
/**
  * @var \App\View\AppView $this
  */
?>
<nav class="large-3 medium-4 columns" id="actions-sidebar">
    <ul class="side-nav">
        <li class="heading"><?= __('Actions') ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Projects'), ['action' => 'index']) ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Projects Group'), ['controller' => 'ProjectsGroup', 'action' => 'index']) ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('New Projects Group'), ['controller' => 'ProjectsGroup', 'action' => 'add']) ?></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="projects form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
    <?= $this->Form->create($project) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Project') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->control('title');
            echo $this->Form->control('description');
            echo $this->Form->control('logo');
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

Controller/ProjectsController.php

```
    <?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;

/**
 * Projects Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\ProjectsTable $Projects
 */
class ProjectsController extends AppController
{

    /**
     * Index method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $projects = $this->paginate($this->Projects);

        $this->set(compact('projects'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['projects']);
    }

    /**
     * View method
     *
     * @param string|null $id Project id.
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null
     * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function view($id = null)
    {
        $project = $this->Projects->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['ProjectsGroup']
        ]);

        $this->set('project', $project);
        $this->set('_serialize', ['project']);
    }

    /**
     * Add method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null Redirects on successful add, renders view otherwise.
     */
    public function add()
    {
        $project = $this->Projects->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $project = $this->Projects->patchEntity($project, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Projects->save($project)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The project has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The project could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $this->set(compact('project'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['project']);
    }

    /**
     * Edit method
     *
     * @param string|null $id Project id.
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null Redirects on successful edit, renders view otherwise.
     * @throws \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function edit($id = null)
    {
        $project = $this->Projects->get($id, [
            'contain' => []
        ]);
        if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
            $project = $this->Projects->patchEntity($project, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Projects->save($project)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The project has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The project could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $this->set(compact('project'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['project']);
    }

    /**
     * Delete method
     *
     * @param string|null $id Project id.
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null Redirects to index.
     * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function delete($id = null)
    {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
        $project = $this->Projects->get($id);
        if ($this->Projects->delete($project)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The project has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The project could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
        }

        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
}
```

Cheers.

---

Edit. 
As I am thinking I can add an 'author' column to projects table, so user which creates project will be automatically its author. However, it still doesn't fix the problem of assigning other users to projects. And I would like to have it done via project controller & project add / edit view.

Comment: Have you checked out this section in the docs https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#using-the-through-option ? It covers how to set up that many-to-many association at the Table level. Also https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-data-to-the-join-table will cover how to save the association automatically from POST data (there's indeed no need to have a separate projects_helper controller)

Comment: Mention the cakephp version in your question..And you mentioned Users table two times..may be second one must be projects table.

Comment: I am using the newest version of cake.
All I had to do was add foreign keys to project_users table, and then just $this->belongToMany... in model.

Thanks though!